# jQuery .append() in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried looking for an answer here but all of the questions related to my issue are a bit too complicated for someone who just started learning JavaScript like me.

I want to create a grid of divs with js/jquery based on user input (eg: if user chooses width = 16, then he will see a 16x16 grid).

Now, I figured, I'll add a DOM element with `var $smallDiv = $('<div class="smallDiv"></div>');`

And here is the loop that adds the needed number of divs based on user input:

```
function addDiv() {
$('#container').append($smallDiv);
}
for (i = 1; i <= divCounter * divCounter; i++){
addDiv();
}
```

The problem is that this will always create only one div. The loop runs the required number of times, I've checked this using console.log(). So it clearly works, but I get the feeling that each time it loops, the new div overwrites the previous. That wasn't my expectation of .append().

I've managed to get around the problem by making the $smallDiv variable a normal one (removing $ from its value, making it just text) but I would love to know how are these two variables different and why does one work in the above scenario but the other does not.

And make it easy on me, I just started learning JS/jQuery.

Comment: Can you add _complete_ HTML and JS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the loop, you are appending the same dom element reference(`$smallDiv`) multiple times, which means the element will be added only once.

Instead in each iteration of the loop, you need to create new instance - you can use [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone) to do that.

```
function addDiv() {
    $('#container').append($smallDiv.clone());
}
```

Comment: A. You need to use nested loop to create multiple lines but not only 1. B. A better way is to generate the full html and only than append it to `#container', because the most "heavy" action is the DOM's manipulation, and it's better to do it as fewer as it possible.

Comment: Better, you can add comment `A` to the fiddle and it will be perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Arun P Johny solution, this seems to work as well:

```
var smallDiv = '<div class="smallDiv"></div>'

function addDiv() {
    $('#container').append(smallDiv);
}

for (i = 1; i <= divCounter * divCounter; i++){
    addDiv();
}
```

This way its not the same dom element but instead we use a simple string for append.